# Android: How to get the button drawable using current theme of a RadioButton?

Tags: java, android, radio-button, themes, drawable

I am changing the button drawable of a RadioButton within `onBindViewHolder` of RecyclerView.Adapter for certain conditions.

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Now, How to restore the original button drawable? Since when we scroll, the view holder holds the old button drawable (transparent) of some other item.

This is what I tried:

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, android.R.drawable.radiobutton_off_background));
```

but it results in this:

[image]

instead of the original one like this:

[image]

It is not applying the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle`

Answer (score 0):

> only works on **api level 21** or above

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:checked="true"
    android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"/>
```

> **values/colors.xml** put your color in this case a reddish one:

```
<color name="your_color">#e75748</color>
```

Result:
[image: optionbotton]